# Dynamically create tables based on dictionaries

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am trying to convert XML files into SQL Databases.
The parsing works great (20s for a 200MB XML file), but the amount of table columns is always different.

After parsing, the rows are available within a `rows[rownumber][columnname]` dictionary.
I basically know how I can create tables. Samplecode:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
```

But I do not know how to do that dynamically. The columns would be `varchar`, `integer`, `datetime`, and `text`

My attempt would be to iterate trough the dictionary keys:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    for col in rows[0].keys():
       self[col] = Column(String(250))
```

But I have no idea how I would set the appropriate types to the columns. 
Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you have specific set of names of columns in your database? You can try to map the `name->Column(Type)` value in a dictionary. You can also have a default column that is always mapped to type `String`. I wrote about how to call appropriate functions from a dict in my blog [here](http://kirankoduru.github.io/python/python-dict-functions.html). Maybe it helps.

Comment: If you are doing this with straight SQL or are you using django or some other framework?

Comment: I kind of question the whole idea of creating SQL tables here: you already have a dictionary with all the data you need - can you use it for your look-ups as  well?

Comment: I need to create the database for using it with my webapp. I use sqlalchemy as ORM. Thansk, I will have a Look into your Blog